# Filter centered column SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to create a query from an Oracle DB.
that is, `SELECT FROM and WHERE`.
the column "ORG" is centered and always has 4 letters. I would like to filter that on one specific Item/ value.
I already have `WHERE ORG = 'HHAH'`
or with `SBSTRG (ORG ...:`
somehow nothing works.
Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking... Please add sample tables, show what your expected output is, and add your full attempted queries instead of snippets. Also, what do you mean by 'centered'?

Comment: What is a centered column? What is SBSTRG?

Comment: It ist just a column in the Oracle DB with 4 letters in the middle/ centered. There are 7 space bars bevor

Comment: 4 letters in the middle? What does that mean? I'd assume that every word more than 4 letters has four letters in the middle.

Comment: I have values of '       HHAH       ' instead of 'HHAH' in the column. There are blanks befor and after the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have values of ' HHAH ' instead of 'HHAH' in the column. There are blanks befor and after the value

You could remove the leading and trailing spaces with [the `trim()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRIM.html):

```
WHERE TRIM(ORG) = 'HHAH'
```

Using a function on the column value will prevent any index on that column being used (as will `like` with a leading wildcard); unless you add a function-based index for the trimmed value there isn't much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the [`LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) operator:

```
WHERE ORG LIKE '%HHAH%'
```

or

```
WHERE ORG LIKE '%' || 'HHAH' || '%'
```

to search for values conatining `'HHAH'`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend fixing the data:

```
update t
    set org = trim(org);
```

I see no reason to be storing spaces in the name of an `org`.  If you need spaces for reporting purposes, put them there.